# Android Location From network when No GPS returns null

Tags: android, gps, location

I have a code to get location from GPS, but if there is no GPS enabled then i want to use the Network. The GPS Section is working so far, but the NETWORK section returns null location, why is that?. here is my code.

```
private static final long MINIMUNDIST = 1;
private static final long MINTME = 1000;
protected LocationManager locationMan;
protected Button mybutton;

mybutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            showCurrentLocation();
        }
    });

protected void showCurrentLocation(){
    boolean gpsOn = locationMan.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    boolean netOn = locationMan.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    Location loc;
    if (gpsOn){
        loc = locationMan.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    }
    else if (netOn){
        loc = locationMan.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "BOth GPS and NETWORK are OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        loc = null;
    }
    if (loc != null){
        String latText = String.format("%1$s" ,  loc.getLatitude());
        String logText = String.format("%1$s" ,  loc.getLongitude());
        TextView latTView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView longtext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        latTView.setText("Latitude :" + latText);
        longtext.setText("Longtude :"  + logText);
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Null location?!!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}


private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {



            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {


            }



            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) {



            }



            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {



            }



            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {


            }



        }
```

my manifest file contains all the permission needed for the task

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

And by the way, i am testing the app on real phone via USB debugging.

Comment: please give the internet permission also

Comment: @Nithinlal, i already did but still nothing

Comment: u get new the latitude and longitude on onLocationChanged method in MyLocationListener

Comment: so change the 
 if (loc != null){
        String latText = String.format("%1$s" ,  loc.getLatitude());
        String logText = String.format("%1$s" ,  loc.getLongitude());
        TextView latTView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView longtext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        latTView.setText("Latitude :" + latText);
        longtext.setText("Longtude :"  + logText);
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Null location?!!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

Comment: the above code to onLocationChanged methode

Comment: add a new line in the top of the method loc=location

Comment: u have to get the location for the first time some time required. Locationlistener is a class we get the current location,when the location is get it automatically listen by the listener so u get the updated location only in the listener class

Comment: So what do you think is the best method to get location from Network when GPS is unavailable depending on my code?

Comment: Nithinlal is telling you to add code to onLocationChanged method. Besides that, do you have the wifi connection on on your device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The location listener method returns null until it founds a lock on a location.The Network provider location takes few seconds or even minutes to have a lock on a location so it is required to wait until there is a lock on a location.

Answer (score 1):

I recently worked on GPS as well and I followed, [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/), and it works okay (you may need to fix some portion to make functional for other features..)

```
public Location getLocation(){
    try{
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        //getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);


        if(!isGPSEnabled){

        }else{
            this.canGetLocation = true;

            if(isNetworkEnabled){
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,  this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");

                if(locationManager != null){
                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if(location != null){
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        speed = location.getSpeed();
                    }
                }
            }

            if(isGPSEnabled){
                if(location == null){


                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates((LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER), MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");

                    if(locationManager != null){
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                        if(location != null){
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}
```

And you must add the required permissions to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file as below

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Just for Testing you can add one more permission to use mock location.

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
```